# EOS Application Specific Chains

Tags: eosio-code

With the cost of RAM for provisioning users with accounts and storing data, the main chain feels expensive.

As a solution I'd like to explore the setting up of application specific chains which start with just 2-3 nodes and expand as supporters of the application want to get involved.

Is there a step by step guide anywhere on how I could setup these little chains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a good tutorial about setting up your own public or private blockchain from the scratch.

[Nodeos Bios Boot Sequence](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence)

And there's also a project working a toolkit for easy setup of eosio-based chains.

[EosInABox](https://eosinabox.com/)